# Magento Layered Navigation saying items exist on search / empty pages

Tags: php, magento, navigation

I've just tried activating layered navigation on my Magento store, and It's showing like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WY5R.jpg

It seems to think a selection of items are already picked - even on search results with only one result.

Is there a way I can debug this to try and find out where it's getting the items from?

It's not selecting all my items either, as I have something like 1000 items on my store. It's only picking a handful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary from the image you have posted.  You control the products that are in the Layered Navigation through the product's attributes, so what you are seeing and the results you get will depend on the attributes you have set up, which products have which attributes, and the attribute settings.

In Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes you edit the attribute and in the Frontend Properties settings you can dictate whether that attribute will be used in Layered Navigation and the Search results for Layered Navigation.

Also, bear in mind that the 'Filterable (No Results) option will allow the filter to appear even if there are no products matching it, that might also be contributing to your issues;

[image]

Comment: The problem is I've searched for a product with the Stardot manufacturer that is the only item returned. Manufacturer attribute is set to Filterable (with results), but it shows up about a quarter of the manufacturers that I have in the system. 

If it was Filterable (no results) shouldn't it show every item, and if it was Filterable (with results) shouldn't it show just the Stardot manufacturer?